# How to use read_table or fread in this particular case?

Tags: r, download, data.table, readr

As you know, `read.table` in `R` is a very useful but slow function, particularly when it comes to read big databases. In order to face problems related with that function, there exists functions such as `read_table` and `fread` from `readr` and `data.table` packages. Unfortunately, their arguments differ from `read.table` which made me difficult to replicate this example:

```
download.file("https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz", "mov_title")
download.file("https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.ratings.tsv.gz", "mov_rating")

title <- read.table("mov_title", sep="\t", header=TRUE,
    fill=TRUE, na.strings="\\N", quote="")

rating <- read.table("mov_rating", sep="\t", header=TRUE,
    fill=TRUE, na.strings="\\N", quote="")
```

Basically I want to use `fread` or `read_table` (or both if it's possible) to create my "title" and "rating" databases. Any advice or reference will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to work just fine... `data.table::fread()` can handle gz-files.

Set `\t` (=tab) as separator.
Since some movie-titles contain quotes, set quotes to nothing; `quote = ""`. (or not, and just accept the warnings).

```
library( data.table )
title  <- fread( "https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz", 
                 sep = "\t", quote = "" )
rating <- fread( "https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.ratings.tsv.gz", 
                 sep = "\t", quote = "" )
```

Comment: It was so easy... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

fread suppots **.gz** file as well as reading from a url. You can keep rest of the arguments same as those in **read.table**

```
library(data.table)
title=fread("https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz",sep = "\t",quote = "",na.strings = "\\N",header = T,fill = T) 

> dim(title)
[1] 6518809       9
> 
> 
> head(title)
      tconst titleType           primaryTitle          originalTitle isAdult startYear endYear
1: tt0000001     short             Carmencita             Carmencita       0      1894      NA
2: tt0000002     short Le clown et ses chiens Le clown et ses chiens       0      1892      NA
3: tt0000003     short         Pauvre Pierrot         Pauvre Pierrot       0      1892      NA
4: tt0000004     short            Un bon bock            Un bon bock       0      1892      NA
5: tt0000005     short       Blacksmith Scene       Blacksmith Scene       0      1893      NA
6: tt0000006     short      Chinese Opium Den      Chinese Opium Den       0      1894      NA
   runtimeMinutes                   genres
1:              1        Documentary,Short
2:              5          Animation,Short
3:              4 Animation,Comedy,Romance
4:             NA          Animation,Short
5:              1             Comedy,Short
6:              1                    Short
```